# Pass user input value through props in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 component, how do I pass user entered value through onChange to parent component? I'm able to pass the 'trigger' upon onChange, but how to pass the value along?

https://jsfiddle.net/gboaxm30

```
var InputComp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" onChange={this.props.newVal} />
     </div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
  return {
     inputVal: 0
  }
  },
  inputChangedHandler(props) {
    //set user changed value to inputVal
    console.log(props)
  },
  render() {
    return(
    <div>
        <InputComp newVal={this.inputChangedHandler}/>
      <h4>{this.state.inputVal}</h4>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a function on the `onChange` event of the child component and then access the value of input like `e.target.value` and then pass it to the parent component like `this.props.newVal(e.target.value);`

```
var InputComp = React.createClass({
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.newVal(e.target.value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
     </div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
  return {
     inputVal: 0
  }
  },
  inputChangedHandler(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this.setState({inputVal: val});
  },
  render() {
    return(
    <div>
        <InputComp newVal={this.inputChangedHandler}/>
      <h4>{this.state.inputVal}</h4>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gboaxm30/1/)**

Comment: oh I can get it before it got passed, which one is better? the first or second option? the second option is I can get it on the `inputChangedHandler ` using e.target.val too.

Comment: refs are for you to access an object like you do with document.getElementById similarly you can access by ref name as this.refs.name

Comment: Both are equally good. Only thing with the above method is that if there are multiple input and selects you can handle it internally as to which function from parent to call

Answer (score 1):

I've made a demo for you here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/pEAQzV

The idea is to use the so-called controlled input as defined in the React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

```
 var InputComp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      userInput: ''
    };
  },

  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      userInput: event.target.value
    });
    this.props.newVal(event.target.value);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         InputComp
         <input type="text" 
                value={this.state.userInput}
                onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});




var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
     inputVal: ''
    };
  },

  inputChangedHandler(valueFromChild) {
    console.log('valuefromChild:', valueFromChild);
    this.setState({
      inputVal: valueFromChild
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputComp newVal={this.inputChangedHandler}/>
        <h4>{this.state.inputVal}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: If you see I have the same demo set up in my answer :)

Comment: Nice :) It's a very common pattern. Although I'm using the controlled input.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the value from the event

```
  inputChangedHandler(e) {
      //set user changed value to inputVal
      console.log(e.target.value)
  },
```

Comment: that simple? just change this part? I don't have to pass the value from the onChange event, but it came with the whole handler?

Comment: What if it's a `select`?

Comment: the value is already passed with the event - so yea you can get it from e.target.value. same as with select - just like you would do in vanilla js.

Comment: I see then what `refs` is for?

Comment: ref is used to access child elements from the parents like `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput)` for example, but you dont need it here, and its a good practice to avoid using it when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I thinktThis would be helpful for you.

```
let InputComp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      textVal: "",
    };
  },
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ textVal: e.target.value });
    this.props.newVal(this.state.textVal);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.textVal}
        />
      </div>
    );
  },
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      inputVal: 0,
    };
  },
  inputChangedHandler(val) {
    this.setState({ inputVal: val });
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InputComp newVal={this.inputChangedHandler} />
        <h4>{this.state.inputVal}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```